# A Windows application : Show live output of results(stdout?) of prespecified command

Tags: command-line, cygwin, autohotkey, find

I am looking for a application that works in the following manner :

1. The application shows/has an input area/box.
2. And it runs a pre-specified command/application (using the input as paramas) and shows the commands output parallely (live) as I type.

So something like find-as-you-type functionality of a browser except that instead of searching an html page, its running a custom command and showing the commands output (in another windows/notepad/anything - I am not particular how)

The application can be based on gui/console/cygwin/autohotkey script. I am ok with all

Does there exist something like this ?

I am sure an autohotkey pro can make something like this quite easily. So if one is around please do share how it could be done / any tips on what to look for.

Thanks

Edit: Answering the questions:

> When you say you want the output to be live, would it be acceptable if the output was shown only after each command was executed in full?

I think not, The command should be run on each keydown event, without having to press enter.

> Trying to re-execute variations of a command? Would you clear the output window each time a new command is executed such that the output window only shows the output for the last command executed?

Yes! Precisely.

The command itself won't be complex, would return something in milliseconds...

Comment: When you say you want the output to be live, would it be acceptable if the output was shown only after each command was executed in full?  In other words, if you look at RunWait documentation for AutoHotkey it can do this and grab the output after each command, but if you were to do a dir/s on your entire harddisk I don't think it would have any output until a half-hour later when the command completed, unlike a regular command prompt which would show the output scrolling.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with an input and an output window?  Trying to re-execute variations of a command?  Would you clear the output window each time a new command is executed such that the output window only shows the output for the last command executed?

Comment: Answered your questions by editing question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in AutoHotkey.  Doesn't do even basic things like being able to resize the window but it might work for you.  Also, the first input box isn't labeled but it's the working directory to use.  After you type a command and hit enter then it will turn on auto-update after that and automatically run on every keystroke thereafter.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; CommandConsole.ahk
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Main:
    myTitle := "Command Console"
    myFont  := "Courier New"
    myFontSize := "10"
    xMargin := 10, yMargin := 10
    xSpace  := 10, ySpace  := 10

    txtWidth  := 700, butWidth := 100

    inputHeight  := 20
    outputHeight := 600

    firstRun := True
    immediateExec := False

    Gui, Add, Button, x0 y0 w0 h0 default gbutSubmit,       ; default button used for grabbing text entry

    vertical := yMargin
    Gui, Font, % "s" myFontSize, % myFont
    Gui, Add, Edit, % "x" xMargin " y" vertical " w" txtWidth " h" inputHeight " vWorkingDir", .        ; current directory is default working directory, i.e., "."
    Gui, Font

    Gui, Add, Button, % "x" xMargin+txtWidth+xSpace " y" vertical " w" butWidth " h" 2*inputHeight+yspace " gButAuto vButCaption", % "Auto-Update`n" . (immediateExec ? "On" : "Off")

    vertical += inputHeight + ySpace
    Gui, Font, % "s" myFontSize, % myFont
    Gui, Add, Edit, % "x" xMargin " y" vertical " w" txtWidth " h" inputHeight " gEditUpdated vtxtInput",  
    Gui, Font


    Gui, Font, % "s" myFontSize, % myFont
    vertical += inputHeight + ySpace
    Gui, Add, Edit, % "x" xMargin " y" vertical " w" txtWidth+xSpace+butWidth " h" outputHeight " vtxtOutput " ; disabled"
    Gui, Font

    vertical += OutputHeight+yMargin
    Gui, Show, % "w" txtWidth+xSpace+butWidth+2*xMargin " h" vertical, % myTitle

    GuiControl, focus, txtInput     ; focus on the command input for entry
return

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; GuiClose() - Exit app when GUI closes
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GuiClose() {
    ExitApp
}

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; butSubmit() - No-size button to capture Enter keystrokes when auto-update is off
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
butSubmit() {
    global
    EnterWasPressed := True
    if firstRun and !immediateExec  ; set auto-update after the first command is executed if it's not set already
        ButAuto()
    else
        EditUpdated()           ; on subsequent
}

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; EditUpdated()
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EditUpdated() {
    global      ; easy access to GUI vars

    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    ;tooltip Edit was updated: %txtInput%   

    if immediateExec or EnterWasPressed { 
        guiControl,, txtOutput, % RunWaitOneB(txtInput, WorkingDir)
        EnterWasPressed := False
    }

    lasttxtInput := txtInput
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    if (txtInput<>lastTxtInput)
        setTimer, EditUpdated, -1

    return
}

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; ButGo() - Called every time the user clicks auto-execute True/False Button
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ButAuto() {
    global
    immediateExec := !immediateExec
    guiControl,, butCaption, % "Auto-Update`n" . (immediateExec ? "On" : "Off")
    if immediateExec
        EditUpdated()
}

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; RunWaitOne() - From AutoHotkey Help for RunWait (has annoying command prompt flash up)
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RunWaitOne(command) {
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")      ; WshShell object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C " command)  ; Execute a single command via cmd.exe
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()                ; Read and return the command's output
}

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; RunWaitOneB() - Get stdout by writing to a temp file vs. reading the buffer
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RunWaitOneB(command, WorkingDir:=".") {
    tmpFile := A_Temp . "\temp.txt"
    FileDelete, %tmpFile%
    RunWait, %comspec% /c %command% > %tmpFile%, %WorkingDir%, Hide
    FileRead, output, %tmpFile%
    return output
}
```